# about admob policy 2 ads in the same page

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, policy

1-If  I made a banner ad from admob at the begging of the page
and the other one at the end but from other company is that against admob police ?

2-also if I use banner ad and native ad in the same page from admob is that against the policy ?

Comment: please take a look at this article on discouraged banner implementation, as long as you adhere to those. You can have multiple ads on the same page. There is no such restriction https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions, even we can use two native ads on the same activity. Like this we can use native and banner in the same activity, I've tried.
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start#when_to_request_ads

Use can follow this to implement native ads